# Trying to calculate score on the basis of collision using collide() in p5.js

Tags: javascript, game-physics, p5.js

I am trying to calculate my game score using the collide() method from p5.play.js such that whenever the `apple` hits the `hero`, the score increments by one. Everything is working fine except the score. My score keeps on updating irrespective of the fact that the `apple` collides with the `hero` or not.

Here is my `draw()` function

```
function draw() {

    background(backdrop);
    drawSprite(hero);

    for(i=0; i<apples.length; i++)
    {
        apples[i].spr.collide(hero, scoreUpdate);

        if(cell[i] == 1 && previousGen[i] == 0)
        {
            apples[i].fall();
        }
        else if(cell[i] == 0 && previousGen[i] == 1 )
        {
            obstacles[i].fall();
        }
    }

    text("score: " + score, width-100, 20);
    for(i=0; i<apples.length; i++)
    {
        if(apples[i].spr.position.y > height)
        {
            generationEnd = true;
            apples[i].spr.position.y=100;
            obstacles[i].b.position.y=100;
        }
        else
        {
            generationEnd=false;
            break; 
        }
    }


    if(generationEnd==true)
        newGeneration();
}
```

And here is the `scoreUpdate()` function

```
function scoreUpdate(apple, hero)
{
    score++;
    apple.position.y = height+10;
}
```

Can anybody help me fix this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed it. The problem was that I was calling collide() function irrespective of the fact that the apple is falling or not. I called the collide function right after the apple was falling so it worked for some reason and it even sounds logical to check collision if the apple has fallen. Here is the updated `draw()` function

```
function draw() {

    background(backdrop);
    drawSprite(hero);

    for(i=0; i<apples.length; i++){

        if(cell[i] == 1 && previousGen[i] == 0){
            apples[i].fall();
            apples[i].spr.collide(hero, scoreUpdate);
        }
        else if(cell[i] == 0 && previousGen[i] == 1 ){
            obstacles[i].fall();
        }

    }
    text("score: " + score, width-100, 20);
    for(i=0; i<apples.length; i++){
        if(apples[i].spr.position.y > height){
            generationEnd = true;
            apples[i].spr.position.y=100;
            obstacles[i].b.position.y=100;
        }
        else{
            generationEnd=false;
            break; 
        }
    }


    if(generationEnd==true)
        newGeneration();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware the Javascript semicolon injection. Always start a code block on the same line as the if/for/for...in/while/etc. statements, otherwise a semicolon will be inserted at the end of that line, ending the if statement and making it only execute ";" if the statement is true. Your other code, therefore, is not actually in the if statement. Same goes for your loops.

Fixed JS:

```
function draw() {

    background(backdrop);
    drawSprite(hero);

    for(i=0; i<apples.length; i++){
        apples[i].spr.collide(hero, scoreUpdate);

        if(cell[i] == 1 && previousGen[i] == 0){
            apples[i].fall();
        }
        else if(cell[i] == 0 && previousGen[i] == 1 ){
            obstacles[i].fall();
        }
    }

    text("score: " + score, width-100, 20);
    for(i=0; i<apples.length; i++){
        if(apples[i].spr.position.y > height){
            generationEnd = true;
            apples[i].spr.position.y=100;
            obstacles[i].b.position.y=100;
        }
        else{
            generationEnd=false;
            break; 
        }
    }


    if(generationEnd==true){
        newGeneration();
    }
}
```

And just to be safe:

```
function scoreUpdate(apple, hero){
    score++;
    apple.position.y = height+10;
}
```

Comment: @MuhammadZaidIkhlas Then there must be other problems as well. Keep in mind my edits, though, as what I have said is true.

Comment: @MuhammadZaidIkhlas If the last apple sets generationEnd to false, it overwrites the others setting it to true. Is this intended?

Comment: yes it is intended since the apples are falling on the basis of a cellular automata